# Why do I need to update the service reference after I moved the WCF from one domain to another?

Tags: wcf

I do understand that I need to change the endpoint URL in config file.. I did change the endpoint URL but it doesn't work. It doesn't show any exception.. The problem is that I can't get any data from that service.

The only solution that I found so far is that I need to update the service reference in order to get the data.

Why do I need to update the service reference after I moved the WCF from one domain to another? Shouldnt changing the endpoint URL in config be just work?

Comment: Check the security settings for your binding. Could be that you have used the default Windows credentials which are no longer valid for the domain that you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that excpetion/behavior is related to EndpointIdentity. On changing the domain, you not only require to change the URL address but EndpointIdentity based on what EndpointIdentity is used by Service.

Just for clarification, I'm referring this element,

```
<service>
  <endpoint>
   **<dns/servicePrincipalName/userPrincipalName>**
```

HTH,
Amit